Divisor on $\mathbb{C}$ explanation
I was looking at an article and end up at the following statements:
For a divisor $\nu$ on $\mathbb{C}$ and for a positive integer $n$ (may be infinity) , we define the counting function of $\nu$ by
$$\nu^{[n]}(z)=min \{n, \nu(z)\}, z\in \mathbb{C}$$
$$n(t)=\sum_{|z|\leq t} \nu(z), n^{[n]}(t)=\sum_{|z|\leq t} \nu^{[n]}(z)$$
Can someone explain what the author meant by 'divisor on $\mathbb{C}$'. My domain is Nevanlinna's Value distribution theory, where I usually do not need much of complex manifolds.

I suppose a divisor on $\mathbb C$ is meant to be a function $\mathbb C\to \mathbb Z$ of finite support. We assign to finitely many complex numbers a non-zero integer. Generally by "divisors on some set $X$" one means an element of the free abelian group $\mathbb Z[X]$.
